# How to pass checkbox data into main window function in customtkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm creating a python app with the "customtkinter". I need to open another window when the user clicks on a button and on that window there are 2 options to select and submit. After clicking on submit button need to close that window and pass the selected value into the main window and display them on the log text box.

**This is what I tried;**

```
import customtkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.title("User activity checker")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")
        self.minsize(600, 400)

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # create sidebar frame with widgets
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=5, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="User Activity",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))

        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.click_more_buttons,
                                                        text="Click More Buttons")
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.take_user_input,
                                                        text="Take User input")
        self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.check_user_input,
                                                        text="Check user input")
        self.sidebar_button_3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_4 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.exit,
                                                        text="Exit")
        self.sidebar_button_4.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.appearance_mode_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Appearance Mode:", anchor="w")
        self.appearance_mode_label.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.sidebar_frame,
                                                                       values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                                                       command=self.change_appearance_mode_event)
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # set textbox
        self.log_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Logs", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=16, weight="bold"))
        self.log_label.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, height=400)
        self.textbox.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=1, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")

        self.combobox = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=self, values=["Sample text 1", "Text 2"])
        self.combobox.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ew")
        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, command=self.button_callback, text="Insert Text")
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ew")

        # set default values
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.set("Dark")

    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, new_appearance_mode: str):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", "change the appearance mode \n")
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)

    def button_callback(self):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", self.combobox.get() + "\n")

    def click_more_buttons(self):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", "Click button 1 \n")
        w = customtkinter.CTk()
        w.geometry("300x300")
        w.minsize(300, 300)
        w.title('Select Option')

        l1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=w, text="Select option to process", font=('Century Gothic', 20))
        l1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
        checkbox_1 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=w, text="Select option 1")
        checkbox_1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
        checkbox_2 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(master=w, text="Select option 2")
        checkbox_2.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
        button3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=w, text="Submit")
        button3.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        w.mainloop()

    def take_user_input(self):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", "Click button 2 \n")

    def check_user_input(self):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", "Click button 3 \n")

    def exit(self):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", "Click button 4 \n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Now I need to pass that selected value and process more details with the passed value. And if I am wrong about developing the GUI, Please correct me. I'm new to python and need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `ClickMoreButton` which takes the `CTkTextBox` widget from your main class App. I modified your code and it looks like below:

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"

class ClickMoreButton(customtkinter.CTkToplevel):
    def __init__ (self, text_box=None, **kw):
      self.text_box = text_box
      self.text = ''
      super().__init__(**kw)
      self.geometry("300x300")
      self.minsize(300, 300)
      self.title('Select Option')

      self.l1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Select option to process", font=('Century Gothic', 20))
      self.l1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
      self.var1 = tkinter.IntVar()
      self.checkbox_1 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(self, text="Select option 1", variable=self.var1,
                                                  onvalue=1,
                                                  offvalue=0,command=self.setText)
      self.checkbox_1.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
      self.var2 = tkinter.IntVar()
      self.checkbox_2 = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(self, text="Select option 2", variable=self.var2,
                                                  onvalue=1,
                                                  offvalue=0,command=self.setText)
      self.checkbox_2.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
      self.button3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text="Submit", command=self.submit)
      self.button3.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    def setText(self):
      if self.var1.get() == 1:
        self.text = self.checkbox_1.cget('text')
      if self.var2.get() == 1:
        self.text = self.checkbox_2.cget('text')
    
    def submit(self):
      self.text_box.delete('0.0', customtkinter.END)
      self.text_box.insert('0.0', self.text)
      self.destroy()

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.title("User activity checker")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")
        self.minsize(600, 400)

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        # create sidebar frame with widgets
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=5, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="User Activity",
                                                 font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))

        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.click_more_buttons,
                                                        text="Click More Buttons")
        self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_2 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.take_user_input,
                                                        text="Take User input")
        self.sidebar_button_2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_3 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.check_user_input,
                                                        text="Check user input")
        self.sidebar_button_3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.sidebar_button_4 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, command=self.exit,
                                                        text="Exit")
        self.sidebar_button_4.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.appearance_mode_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Appearance Mode:", anchor="w")
        self.appearance_mode_label.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.sidebar_frame,
                                                                       values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                                                       command=self.change_appearance_mode_event)
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # set textbox
        self.log_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Logs", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=16, weight="bold"))
        self.log_label.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

        self.textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, height=400)
        self.textbox.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=1, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")

        self.combobox = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(master=self, values=["Sample text 1", "Text 2"])
        self.combobox.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ew")
        self.button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=self, command=self.button_callback, text="Insert Text")
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ew")

        # set default values
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.set("Dark")

    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, new_appearance_mode: str):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", "change the appearance mode \n")
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)

    def button_callback(self):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", self.combobox.get() + "\n")

    def click_more_buttons(self):
      self.textbox.insert("insert", "Click button 1 \n")
      my_text = ClickMoreButton(self.textbox)
      my_text.focus()
      my_text.mainloop()

    def take_user_input(self):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", "Click button 2 \n")

    def check_user_input(self):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", "Click button 3 \n")

    def exit(self):
        self.textbox.insert("insert", "Click button 4 \n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```